# Download file extract to specific directory with cURL

Tags: command-line, tar

I wish for the file to download to `~/downloads` and keep the same filename. Then I want that file to be extracted (contents) to the `~/downloads/ok` directory. `~/downloads/ok` directory exists.

```
curl -Lo ~/downloads https://github.com/janeczku/haproxy-acme-validation-plugin/archive/0.1.1.tar.gz | tar zxf -C ~/downloads/ok
```

I get the error: `tar (child): -C: Cannot open: No such file or directory`

Comment: try `Downloads` with a capital `D` not a lower-case `d`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I have renamed it to lowercase on my computer :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're saving the file to some location in curl, then piping to `tar` is pointless: there's no data being transferred over the pipe. And the `f` option in `tar` is for reading from a file (the filename must be the next argument), so that isn't useful in a pipe either. To save to a file and send to a pipe, use `tee`:

```
curl -L https://github.com/janeczku/haproxy-acme-validation-plugin/archive/0.1.1.tar.gz |
  tee ~/downloads/0.1.1.tar.gz |
  tar zx -C ~/downloads/ok
```

Answer (score 1):

you may want

```
(cd ~/downloads && curl -L https://github.com/janeczku/haproxy-acme-validation-plugin/archive/0.1.1.tar.gz && cd ok && tar zxf ../0.1.1.tar.gz)
```

or more readably

```
(
    f='https://github.com/janeczku/haproxy-acme-validation-plugin/archive/0.1.1.tar.gz'
    cd ~/downloads && 
    curl -L $f && 
    cd ok && 
    tar zxf ../${f##*/}
)
```

I'm using parentheses to run the commands in a subshell so your current dir in your current shell is not altered

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the file itself to the destination directory :

```
curl -LOk https://github.com/janeczku/haproxy-acme-validation-plugin/archive/0.1.1.tar.gz > ~/downloads/0.1.1.tar.gz
```

And proceed with the archive extraction.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -SL https://download.example.org/abc.tar.gz | tar -zxC /opt
```

will produce `/opt/abc` folder.

The `-x` for extract, `-z` for `.gz` and `-C` for destination directory,